# Cant access store with mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Im new to react, I'm trying to setup the login system with redux. In my Login component I'm using `mapStateToProps` with the `connect` method that `react-redux` offers.

When I tried to get what I needed from the store It kept saying that it was undefined. This is a snippet of my Login component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    loggingIn: state.authentication.loggedIn,


  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
     actions: bindActionCreators(userActions, dispatch),
     alertActions: bindActionCreators(alertActions, dispatch),

  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

Here's how I tried to combine reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authentication from './userReducer';
import alert from './alertReducer'

    const rootReducer = () => combineReducers({
        authentication,
        alert
    });

    export default rootReducer;
```

However I couldn't access the `logginIn` props in the Login component. After trouble shooting for some frustrating hours I got it to work by removing the arrow function to this:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
```

Can someone tell me why the arrow function didn't work? Thanks

Update: Here's how I imported the root reducer in the index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));


  ReactDOM.render(

  <Provider store={store}>

    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'))



// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Can you post the file where the rootReducer is being used? I just wanted to confirm my suspicions. :)

Comment: you mean where it was connected to the store?

Comment: Did you imported the rootReducer and created a store in your App.js? Show us the code.

Comment: please add the code for all the reducers

Comment: Ive updated the question to show how i imported root reducer

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) tells you to call combineReducers to provide the root reducer. 
The createStore method expects a reducer, not a function to call to get this reducer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Vinicius' answer, you can refactor your `combineReducers()` call even more.

Instead of:

```
const rootReducer = () => combineReducers({
     authentication,
     alert
});

export default rootReducer;
```

which I have seen others do before, I guess personally the less code I need to write the cleaner, as long as it doesn't become esoteric looking, anyway just write it like this:

```
export default combineReducers({
  authentication,
  alert
});
```

You export and call the `combineReducers()` all in one go. Oh and to import it, since we removed `rootReducer` just do:

```
import reducers from "./reducers";

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))
);
```